restoring PostgreSQL database after creating target database
Below code for restoring the database backup works when I run after manually creating the database_restore in postgresql.
os.putenv('PGPASSWORD', password)

from_backup_dir = ".\\Files\\DBBackups\\"

dumper = """ "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\14\\bin\\pg_restore" -h %s -p %s -U %s -d %s -v -F t %s """
file_name = "dbbackup" + file_timestamp + ".backup"
command = dumper % (host, port, user, database_restore,
                    from_backup_dir + "dbbackup2024_07_31_16_00_29_859387.backup")

I want to use the -C option to create the target database instead of manually creating i.e.
dumper = """ "C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\14\\bin\\pg_restore" -h %s -p %s -U %s **-C** -d %s -v -F t %s """ 

But this gives error. Any directions will be helpful.
The error message is :
pg_restore: connecting to database for restore
pg_restore: error: connection to server at "localhost" (::1), port 5432 failed: FATAL:  database "SDEDB1" does not exist
**SDEDB1 was my database_restore

You could start by sharing the error message

Well, I updated the error message in the original post.

Did you create SDEDB1 in lower case or upper case? I bet it's lower case, and now you try to use the upper case name. Advice: Never ever use upper case in object names, like the database name.

I do not intend to create SDEDB1 manually but expect pg_restore to create it before doing the restore when using -C  option. I'm passing database_restore = "SDEDB1" for  -d

What database is used for -d ? That should be an existing database, not the one you want to restore (and create first) Usually you would use the standard database postgres for this.
